# What is the difference between column_name and qualified_col_name?

Tags: oracle

The following query on the standard view [`user_tab_col`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2655.htm):

```
select * from user_tab_cols;
```

returns on Oracle the columns `column_name` and `qualified_col_name`.

What is the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. Could you show a short sample of your output?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Type in `describe user_tab_cols;`

Comment: :D I missed that fact this was a _standard_ table.

Comment: Rather, it's a `View`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qualified_col_name` indicates full column path for XML tables. Basically it stores the expression for this column. For regular columns it will be equal to `column_name`.

If you run:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, qualified_col_name
  from all_tab_cols
 where column_name <> qualified_col_name;
```

you will see returned columns from XML tables in XDB schema.

For example:

```
OWNER  TABLE_NAME       COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE           QUALIFIED_COL_NAME
XDB    XDB$SIMPLE_TYPE  SYS_NC00074$  XDB$APPINFO_LIST_T  "XMLDATA"."RESTRICTION"."MIN_INCLUSIVE"."ANNOTATION"."APPINFO"
```

Update:
For object tables `qualified_col_name` stores expression of type casting and accessing to attribute. For example:

```
create or replace type test1_obj as object(
   n1 number,
   n2 number,
   s1 varchar2(10),
   s2 varchar2(20)
)
not final;

create or replace type test2_obj under test1_obj(
  d1 date,
  d2 date
)
not final;

create table object_table of test1_obj;

select column_name, data_type, qualified_col_name 
  from user_tab_cols
where table_name = 'OBJECT_TABLE'
 order by internal_column_id;
```

For last 2 hidden system columns reserved for instances of type test2_obj we can see:

```
COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE   QUALIFIED_COL_NAME
SYS_NC00010$    DATE        TREAT(SYS_NC_ROWINFO$ AS "TEST"."TEST2_OBJ")."D1"
SYS_NC00011$    DATE        TREAT(SYS_NC_ROWINFO$ AS "TEST"."TEST2_OBJ")."D2"
```